# How to read list with some conditions using python3?

Tags: python

How to read list with some conditions using python3?

By default i want to check the first list with date condition and second as alpha numberic condition and rest all list as numbers conditions. Is it easy to check the condition  in nested list or dictionary ???
      import re

```
  list_1=[["01/01/2019","02/02/2019"],["abc012","def345"],["1","2"],["2.50","3.15"],["4.50","5.55"]]

 for i,string in enumerate(list_1):
     for j in string:
          if re.findall(r"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}", j):
             print(j,"first")
     for k in string:
          if re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]", k):
             print(k,"second")
    for l in string:
          if re.findall(r"[0-9]", l):
           print(l,"third")
```

> Expected Output:

```
01/01/2019,first
02/02/2019,first
abc012 second
def345 second
1 third
2 third
2.50 third
3.15 third
4.50 third
5.55 third
```

Comment: `if re.findall(r"[0-9]", l):` There is something fishy in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this as bellow:

```
for i,string in enumerate(list_1):
    if i == 0 :
       for j in string:
          if re.findall(r"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}", j):
             print(j,"first")
    elif i == 1:
       for k in string:
          if re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]", k):
             print(k,"second")
    else:
       for l in string:
          if re.findall(r"[0-9]", l):
             print(l,"third")
```

Comment: If this code solve your problem, then upvote and approve the answer will be very much appreciated.